# Shielding or jamming ultrasound waves using software

Tags: acoustics, ultrasound

I've downloaded SoniControl and it works somewhat well as a jammer, but I am looking for more options.

I'm trying to shield from or jam Ultrasonic Cross-Device Tracking (uxDT).  (See "data over audio" and "data over sound")

I am a programmer, not an engineer, so my options are somewhat limited. I cannot build a sonic jammer, unless it is only software.

I looked at generating noise at a high frequency via python, but I'm not great at audio signal processing and didn't get very far. Here was my code, much of it copied from Stack Overflow (I did not know how to tweak my python script to generate inaudible ultrasound sound -- unless I just didn't hear it, but I didn't really have a way to test -- I tried setting the sample rate to 1 000 000+):

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
sample_rate = 44100
length_in_seconds = 3
amplitude = 50
noise = stats.truncnorm(-1, 1, scale=min(2**16, 2**amplitude)).rvs(sample_rate * length_in_seconds)
wavfile.write('noise.wav', sample_rate, noise.astype(np.int16))
```

How can this script be improved?

If not, what are other ways for jamming?

I saw in this research paper: https://caslab.csl.yale.edu/publications/matyunin2018zeropermission.pdf that foam helps somewhat. What are other methods for shielding from ultrasound?

Comment: Can you provide more clarity? What are you trying to shield? A room, a computer, a person?

Comment: @EricS the OP is trying to disrupt `Ultrasonic Cross-Device Tracking` ... one device emits an ultrasonic chirp that is picked up by another device ... for example a TV program may have a family eating at McDonald's ... a chirp is emitted by the TV ... smartphone app picks up the chirp and offers McDonald's coupons next time the smartphone is used

Comment: A sample a rate of 44100 won't give you ultrasound.

Comment: @jsotola That's fine, but what is he trying to shield? The phone, the computer?